# How to fix "LoadError in ActionController#create" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, digital-ocean

I have the code from ruby on rails where I want to implement auto-creation of Digitalocean droplets using rails so when I create add new from views and add all the details it should trigger an event in the back end.

Heres my code

gem files

`gem 'droplet_kit'`

`config/initializer/digitalocean.rb`

```rb
    require 'droplet_kit'
    client = DropletKit::Client.new(access_token: ENV['digitalocean_token'])
```

In my Controller

```
  def create
    @hosting = Hosting.new(hosting_params)

    droplet = DropletKit::Droplet.new(hosting_params)
    created = client.droplets.create(droplet)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hosting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hosting, notice: 'Hosting was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hosting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hosting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What I want is to create droplets but in my do account. but instead, the error is

```
    uninitialized constant HostingsController::DropletKit
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot of comments and article I found my answer to this question.
found in this article [Here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/07/ruby-constants/) so heres what I do

1. Create initializer `config/initializer/digitalocean.rb`

   ```rb
   require 'droplet_kit'
   # In Rails, you could put this in config/initializers/digitalocean.rb
   DropletKit.configure do |config|
     config.access_token = ENV['digitalocean_token']
     config.user_agent = 'custom'
   end
   ```
2. Add the constant to the controller

   ```rb
    def create
      @hosting = Hosting.new(hosting_params)
      client =  DropletKit::Client.new(access_token: ENV['digitalocean_token'])
      droplet = DropletKit::Droplet.new(
       name: 'mysite.com', 
       region: 'nyc3', 
       image: 'ubuntu-14-04-x64', 
       size: 's-1vcpu-1gb'
      )
      created = client.droplets.create(droplet)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @hosting.save
         format.html { redirect_to @hosting, notice: 'Hosting was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hosting }
        else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @hosting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
     end
   ```

And That's it.